# Server.UrlEncode(string s)... doesn't

Tags: c#, .net, javascript

Server.UrlEncode("My File.doc") returns "My+File.doc", whereas the javascript escape("My File.doc") returns "My%20File.doc".  As far as i understand it the javascript is corectly URL encoding the string whereas the .net method is not.  It certainly seems to work that way in practice putting http://somesite/My+File.doc will not fetch "My File.doc" in any case i could test using firefox/i.e. and IIS, whereas http://somesite/My%20File.doc works fine.  Am i missing something or does Server.UrlEncode simply not work properly?

Comment: Use URLPathEncode instead for bit before the ? querystring see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4145823/httpserverutility-urlpathencode-vs-httpserverutility-urlencode?lq=1

Comment: Haha, this is probably the best answer given, unfortunately nearly 2 years after it is actually useful.  Oh well at least I will know for future reference.

Comment: :) Actually it looks like Uri.EscapeDataString is the one to use because URLPathEncode does not escape chars such as percent signs  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9400445/how-do-you-correctly-escape-a-document-name-in-net

Comment: Every day is a school day ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use Javascripts [encodeURIComponent()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeURIComponent.asp)/decodeURIComponent() for "round-trip" encoding with .Net's URLEncode/URLDecode.

**EDIT**

As far as I know, historically the "+" has been used in URL encoding as a special substitution for the space char ( ASCII 20 ).  If an implementation does not take the space into consideration as a special character with the '+' substitution, then it still has to escape it using its ASCII code ( hence '%20' ).

There is a really good discussion of the situation at http://bytes.com/topic/php/answers/5624-urlencode-vs-rawurlencode.  It's inconclusive, by the way. RFC 2396 lumps the space with other characters without an unreserved representation, which sides with the '%20' crowd.

RFC 1630 sides with the '+' crowd ( via forum discusion )...

> Within the query string, the plus sign
> is reserved as shorthand notation for
> a space.  Therefore, real plus signs
> must beencoded. This method was used
> to make query URIs easier to pass in
> systems which did not allow spaces.

Also, the core RFCs are...

[RFC 1630](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1630) - Universal Resource Identifiers in WWW

[RFC 1738](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1738) - Uniform Resource Locators (URL)

[RFC 2396](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2396) - Uniform Resource Identifiers (URI): Generic Syntax

Answer (score 4):

> As far as i understand it the javascript is corectly URL encoding the string whereas the .net method is not

Actually they're both wrong!

JavaScript `escape()` should never be used. As well as failing to encode the `+` character to `%2B`, it encodes all non-ASCII characters as a non-standard `%uNNNN` sequence.

Meanwhile `Server.UrlEncode` is not exactly URL-encoding as such, but encoding to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, which should only normally be used for query parameters. Using `+` to represent a space outside of a form `name=value` construct, such as in a path part, is wrong.

This is rather unfortunate. You might want to try doing a string replace of the `+` character with `%20` after encoding with `UrlEncode()` when you are encoding into a path part rather than a parameter. In a parameter, `+` and `%20` are equally good.

Answer (score 3):

A `+` instead of a space is correct URL encoding, as would escaping it to %20. See [this](http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/PERL/node201.html) article (CGI Programming in Perl - URL Encoding).

The `+` is not something that JavaScript can parse, so javascript will escape the space or `+` to `%20`.

Answer (score 2):

Using `System.Uri.EscapeDataString()` serverside and `decodeURIComponent` clientside works.

Comment: The only problem is that System.Uri.EscapeDataString has a max string length of 0xfff0.