# UrlPathEncode vs. UrlEncode

Tags: c#, .net, urlencode

What is the difference between

```
HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode(params);
```

AND

```
HttpUtility.UrlEncode(params);
```

I looked at the MSDN pages 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urlpathencode(v=vs.110).aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urlencode(v=vs.110).aspx

but it only tells you not to use UrlPathEncode, it doesn't tell what the difference is.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HttpServerUtility.UrlPathEncode vs HttpServerUtility.UrlEncode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4145823/httpserverutility-urlpathencode-vs-httpserverutility-urlencode)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7997934/in-asp-net-why-is-there-urlencode-and-urlpathencode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4145823/httpserverutility-urlpathencode-vs-httpserverutility-urlencode)

> The difference is all in the space escaping. UrlEncode escapes them into + sign, UrlPathEncode escapes into %20. + and %20 are only equivalent if they are part of QueryString portion per W3C. So you can't escape whole URL using + sign, only querystring portion.

Comment: This answer should not be the accepted answer. The two methods are very different. 
 HttpUtility.UrlEncode() encodes *everything* in the string.  HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode() encodes only the path.

Answer (score 7):

The difference is one Encodes Url of string and one encodes Path portion (**which means the portion of url before query string**) from Url, Here is the implementation how it looks:

```
 /// <summary>Encodes a URL string.</summary>
 /// <returns>An encoded string.</returns>
 /// <param name="str">The text to encode. </param>
 public static string UrlEncode(string str)
 {
    if (str == null)
    {
        return null;
    }
    return HttpUtility.UrlEncode(str, Encoding.UTF8);
 }
```

and here is implementation of UrlPathEncode:

```
/// <summary>Encodes the path portion of a URL string for reliable HTTP transmission from the Web server to a client.</summary>
/// <returns>The URL-encoded text.</returns>
/// <param name="str">The text to URL-encode. </param>
public static string UrlPathEncode(string str)
{
    if (str == null)
    {
        return null;
    }
    int num = str.IndexOf('?'); // <--- notice this 
    if (num >= 0)
    {
        return HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode(str.Substring(0, num)) + str.Substring(num);
    }
    return HttpUtility.UrlEncodeSpaces(HttpUtility.UrlEncodeNonAscii(str, Encoding.UTF8));
}
```

and msdn also states for `HttpUtility.UrlEnocde`:

> > These method overloads can be used to encode the entire URL, including query-string values.