# When would I use HttpUtility.UrlEncode() instead of HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode()?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, urlencode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [HttpServerUtility.UrlPathEncode vs HttpServerUtility.UrlEncode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4145823/httpserverutility-urlpathencode-vs-httpserverutility-urlencode)

When I call `HttpUtility.UrlEncode(title)` and use that for my URL, IIS gives me a 404.11 error.

From researching it seems I have to use `HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode(title)` due to the + signs, nad this works.

My question is why is there both, and when would I use the non-path one?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4145823/httpserverutility-urlpathencode-vs-httpserverutility-urlencode